# Program that smoothes the enlarged image [python]

Tags: python

I am trying to create a program that smoothes the enlarged image. the way to do it usually is replacing each pixel in an elnarged image by the average of itself and it's neighbours. I did that in the def average function. however I am getting this error:

> newPixel = average(originalPixel,(originalPixel -
>   1),(originalPixel+1)) TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -:
>   'Pixel' and 'int'

My code is the one below, oldPixel is the originalPixel taken from the image:

```
from cImage import*
def average(oldPixel, neighbour1, neighbour2):
    newPixel = (neighbour1 + neighbour2 + oldPixel/3)
    return newPixel






def averagePhoto(image):
    mywin = ImageWin("image",1000,600)
    oldimage = FileImage("image.gif")
    oldimage.draw(mywin)

    width = oldimage.getWidth()
    height = oldimage.getHeight()
    newim = EmptyImage(width,height)

    for row in range(height):
        for col in range(width):
            originalPixel = oldimage.getPixel(col,row)
            newPixel = average(originalPixel,(originalPixel - 1),(originalPixel+1))
            newim.setPixel(col,row,newPixel)

    newim.setPosition(width+1,0)
    newim.draw(myimagewindow)
    myimagewindow.exitOnClick()
```

Can someone figure out what the problem is ?

Thank you

Comment: What is the Type of oldPixel?

Comment: it's an image. so it's grabbing the oldPixel from an image, I will edit that

Comment: I can't tell with your current code, but it seems oldPixel and newPixel are objects of a class perhaps, that don't have defined `__add__` and `__sub__` method.

Comment: When you are subtracting 1 from a value of type Pixel what are you expecting to get?

Comment: @JasonSperske I am expecting to get the pixel before the currentPixel, and the Pixel after it . since I am trying to get the average of the current pixel and it's neighbors.

Comment: Then it looks like you should change your average function to take two pixels.  An individual pixel wouldn't have any notion of it's place in a larger image, any more than a `int` could know that it was part of an array of `int`s.

Comment: you are right. shouldn't it be 3 parameters ? since two neighbors and the current pixel

Comment: I did the edit. however it is still not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to:

```
originalPixel = oldimage.getPixel(col,row)
```

You need:

```
rightNeignbor =  oldimage.getPixel(col+1,row)
leftNeignbor =  oldimage.getPixel(col-1,row)
```

I would advise to include pixels located north, north east, east, south east, south, south west, west, and north west of the given pixel.

Then you need to average the color values I assume.

You need to average out all values (the second parentheses was misplaced):

```
newPixel = (neighbour1 + neighbour2 + oldPixel) / 3
```

Getting back at cImage docs, there are a red, green, blue pixel properties that you may have to average one at a time. When averaging, divide by a floating point number and round to an integer.